# I have written an object to an java file i/o got junk data in that file

Tags: java

I have created an file in  java  which has object written in that file 
file has an text extension but got an junk character.Any tips,program or tutorial  available for that  Please Help.

There is an Package including Bean file

```
package Packageit;

import java.io.*;



public class Object1 implements Serializable
{
private String name;
private String Account;
private String City;




public void setName(String name)
{
   this.name=name;
}

public String getName()
{
 return name;
}

public void setAccount(String Account)
{
this.Account=Account;
}
public String getAccount()
{
 return Account;
}
public void setCity(String city)
{
 this.City=City;
}
public String getCity()
{
 return City;
}

}
```

and calling of that program is here

```
import java.io.*;
import Packageit.*;

public class FilterFlush {
public static void main (String args[])throws IOException
{   Object1 obj = new Object1();
    obj.setName("Girish");
    obj.setAccount("3456");
    obj.setCity("Ahmedabad");
        FileOutputStream f =new FileOutputStream("Tmp.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream ob =new ObjectOutputStream (f);
        ob.writeObject(obj);
        ob.flush();   


}


}
```

here i got an junk data in the output file like

```
Ԁ牳ᄀ慐正条楥⹴扏敪瑣쀱늄㶔楚˱̀L䄇捣畯瑮t䰒慪慶氯湡⽧瑓楲杮䰻Ѐ楃祴q~䰁Ѐ慮敭q~码瑰Ѐ㐳㘵瑰؀楇楲桳
```

please help for solving that junk data

thanks in advance

Comment: please show how you wrote that object to that file, and tell us what you mean by "junk" and what you were expecting instead.

Comment: The problem is probably the character encoding

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `ObjectOutputStream` uses a binary encoding for writing objects.  If you want a somewhat readable version of the object, you can use `XMLEncoder`.  This will give you an xml representation of the fields in your object.

```
Object1 obj = new Object1();
obj.setName("Girish");
obj.setAccount("3456");
obj.setCity("Ahmedabad");
    FileOutputStream f =new FileOutputStream("Tmp.txt");
XMLEncoder ob =new XMLEncoder (f);
    ob.writeObject(obj);
    ob.flush();
```

If you want a truly human readable version of the object, then you should override the toString() method and combine the attributes into a meaningful string.

```
...
public String getCity()
{
 return City;
}

@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return Account + " for " + Name + " in " + City;
}
}
```